# Regex parenthesis Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Would someone please explain me why this returns false?

```
var regex = new RegExp('\([0-9]{3}\)[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}');
return regex.test('(555)555-5555');
```

Is there some other RegExp property that I have to insert?

Is it better not to use the string and does it have any difference using the string or the regex literal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns false because you need to escape the backslash when you define it as a string, like this:

```
var rePhoneNumber = new RegExp('\\([0-9]{3}\\)[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}');
```

But, since it is javascript, you can make a literal definition:

```
var rePhoneNumber = /\([0-9]{3}\)[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}/;
return rePhoneNumber.test('(555)555-5555');
```

Now it return true, since you don't need to escape the backslash.

---

See a working snippet here:

```js
var rePhoneNumber = /\([0-9]{3}\)[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}/;
console.log(rePhoneNumber.test('(555)555-5555'));

var rePhoneNumber2 = new RegExp('\\([0-9]{3}\\)[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}');
console.log(rePhoneNumber2.test('(555)555-5555'));
```

Comment: how would I do that regex inside a string? Just for curiosity

Comment: @Jan What the.... Oh. Why didn't I think of that?

Comment: @some `Some` might have been in a hurry...

Comment: @CaioCésarSilvaGomes Added example of how to escape the string.